# Creating and Emailing Totals Doc from Google Form Responses

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I am trying to create a function that takes form response data and applies it to a template to create a 'completion certificate' with their total scores, then emails them a link to it.

On the certificate, their answers are split into four groups, but I am having trouble creating totals for the each of the answer arrays.

Here is my current code:

```
 function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var emailAddress = e.values[3];

  var disbeliefScore = e.values[4,5,6,7,8].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  var discomfortScore = e.values[9,10,11,12,13].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  var explorationScore = e.values[14,15,16,17,18].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  var acceptanceScore = e.values[19,20,21,22,23].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("fileIdGoesHere"); 
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderIdGoesHere")
  
  var copy = file.makeCopy(lastName + ',' + firstName, folder); 
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  body.replaceText("{{disbeliefscore}}", disbeliefScore);
  body.replaceText("{{discomfortscore}}", discomfortScore);
  body.replaceText("{{explorationscore}}", explorationScore);
  body.replaceText("{{acceptancescore}}", acceptanceScore); 
  
  doc.saveAndClose();

  var url = doc.getUrl();

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Your Leading Change Questionnaire Results Link",{from:"alternative email address to go here", name:"Alternative Name to go here"},url)

 }
```

The code mostly works (replacing text and sending the email), but the replaced text only seems to be the first value of the group, rather than the total.

For example this section:

```
var disbeliefScore = e.values[4,5,6,7,8].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

is essentially behaving as:

```
var disbeliefScore = e.values[4];
```

and ignores the other values and the 'reduce' script.

As a side note, although the emails are being sent, the subject line of the email is coming out as [object Object].

Any help on either of these issues would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

The syntax `Array[index]` can be used to access a single element in the array. You cannot select multiple indexes from an array by using:

```
e.values[4,5,6,7,8]
```

#### Solution:

In order to retrieve a chunk of the array, use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
e.values.slice(4,9)
```

#### Reference:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. So can this be used with the rest of the ‘reduce’ code? Or is this instead of? Thanks again

Comment: @Jaffa I'm not sure what you want to do with `reduce`, but yes, `e.values.slice(4,9)` returns an array, so you can use `reduce` on it: `e.values.slice(4,9).reduce(......)`. `slice` doesn't replace `reduce` in any case.

Comment: @lamblichus the reduce is purely to provide a total value for the elements within the slice (for example if each of the [4], [5], [6]…etc in my original code had a value of 1 in the corresponding response data, the ‘reduce’ would be to create a total of 5) which would then be applied to the temple doc. 

I’m certainly not tied to it though if there are any more elegant solutions. 

Hope that all made sense.

Comment: @Jaffa Cool, so you can go ahead and use `reduce` on the value returned by `slice`. The problem in your code was not in the reduce but in `e.values[4,5,6,7,8]`, so everything should be fine now. Did you test your code after making the modifications I suggested?

Comment: @lamblichus not quite, sadly. The reduce code doesn't seem to be working as the values are just listed one after the other in the updated template doc. Here is the updated code segment:
`var disbeliefScore = e.values.slice(4,8).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
 var discomfortScore = e.values.slice(9,13).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
 var explorationScore = e.values.slice(14,18).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
 var acceptanceScore = e.values.slice(19,23).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Comment: I have since tidied up the code section in my previous comment to:

`var disbeliefScore = e.values.slice(4,8).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
  var discomfortScore = e.values.slice(9,13).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
  var explorationScore = e.values.slice(14,18).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
  var acceptanceScore = e.values.slice(19,23).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });` 

sadly this also produces the same list of values as before in the updated template doc. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Jaffa Most likely you have strings, and you're treating them as numbers. Convert them to numbers in your reduce function `function(a, b) { return Number(a)+Number(b) }`. Also, the second parameter of slice is exclusive, so you might want to use e.g. `e.values.slice(4,9)` instead of `e.values.slice(4,8)`

Comment: @lamblichus Thank you for this, I will try out and let know the results. Thanks again for your help on this overall, much appreciated.

Comment: @lamblichus That's worked! Thank you so much for your help. My last query would be how to get the code working for a Google Slides-based template file? I've updated the code to the correct file IDs and changed the reference 'DocumentApp' to 'SlidesApp', and the template file is being copied and resaved correctly, but the text isn't being replaced. Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated, but it's good to know the script works for Google Docs files at least! Thanks again.

Comment: @Jaffa For slides, you would not use `doc.getBody`, and instead of `replaceText` you would use [replaceAllText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#replacealltextfindtext,-replacetext): e.g. `var pres = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId()); pres.replaceAllText("{{disbeliefscore}}", disbeliefScore);`

Comment: Thank you @lamblichus will try this and update with results.

Comment: @lamblichus, sadly the updated script refuses to work and returns the following error: 'autoFillGoogleDocFromForm Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType formSubmit' so, due to time constraints,  I'll continue with the Google Docs version of the script instead. Thank you though.

Comment: @lamblichus, as I now consider my main question answered, I wanted to post the final working code to this page. What is best practice for this? Should I answer my own question with the updated code and tagging you in it for reference? Or is there a more advisable way? Thanks

Comment: @Jaffa If the updated code is based on the changes I suggested in my answer, the way to go would be to accept this answer (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you want to add the whole code, you can edit that answer and add the code there. About the `Slides` thing, I'd suggest you to post a new question for that.